# Can't find directory on Mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal, notepad

I have an wordtangler document saved as `ex1.py` under a folder I named `lpthw`, but I can't open it using a terminal.

I open the terminal and `cd` to the folder `lpthw`. Then, I write python `ex1.py`, but I get an error saying:

```
python: can't open file 'ex1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I list the directory using `ls lpthw`, there is nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ls -a` to list the contents of the folder including hidden files.

If there is still no results, the file is probably elsewhere and you can try to find it running `find . -name "ex1.py"` at your root folder.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find the other two files in my lpthw folder. Still wasn't able to find ex1.py using both "ls -a" and "find . - name "ex2.py" . I was able to get it when it was in a different folder though.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file actually in the folder? My only thoughts about this is that the file is actually saved in a different folder OR the file might be under a different name. What does ls command show?

Comment: The ls command shows nothing. I was able to open it when I moved the file to a different folder. When it was in my lpthw folder , I could not open it. I have three files in there and none of it opens. But when I moved it to a different folder, I was able to python ex1.py and it open just fine.

Comment: From what cosme says, it's probably hidden or something to do with the link in that folder. Put it back in the lpthw folder and try using the command Cosme suggested

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find the other half of what I was looking for.